# Tablix em branco

Tags: c#, winforms, reportviewer

estou tentado utiliza o Report Viewer, mas os dados do Tablix fica em branco

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
Load do formulário:

```
reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(new Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportDataSource("Tablix1", NCategoria.Mostrar()));
```

Camada de Negócios

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Report Viewer

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Nome das colunas:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Camada de Dados

```html
 public DataTable Mostrar()
        {
            DataTable DtResultado = new DataTable("categoria");
            SqlConnection SqlCon = new SqlConnection();
            try
            {
                SqlCon.ConnectionString = Conexao.Cn;
                SqlCommand SqlCmd = new SqlCommand();
                SqlCmd.Connection = SqlCon;
                SqlCmd.CommandText = "spmostrar_categoria";
                SqlCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                SqlDataAdapter sqlDat = new SqlDataAdapter(SqlCmd);
                sqlDat.Fill(DtResultado);
            }
            catch
            {
                DtResultado = null;
            }
            return DtResultado;
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Saudações.
Vou postar como eu faço e veja se ajuda. 
Primeiro tenha certeza que seu `DataTable` está trazendo os dados do banco.
Depois altere o códio e teste para ver se vai funcionar.
A única diferença que vejo é que você usa o `DataTable teste` e eu uso uma `Collection`.

```
private void frmRecategoria_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   DataTable teste = Ncategoria.Mostrar();

   //carrega a tabela do reportviewer
   reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(new Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportDataSource("NomeDoDataSet_doTablix", teste));

this.ReportViewer1.RefreshReport();
}
```

Tenha certeza que em sua tabela as colunas estejam com os nomes idênticos ao do `DataTable`, exemplo: **IdCategoria**, **DescCategoria**.

Comment: Cara não deu certo, até essa linha eu recebo as informações http://prntscr.com/gvevtp

Comment: Em suas `Tablix` coloque o nome das colunas igual está no banco.
**Categoria =** ID_categoria,
**Descrição =** Desc_categoria.
Procure postar o código no lugar de print da tela, fica mais fácil de identificar o erro.
O print escondeu uma parte importante do código

Comment: Cara eu já tentei de varias formas e mesmo assim não consigo, eu atualizei o tópico

Comment: No código do Load que você informou dentro dos parênteses**("Tablix1", NCategoria.Mostrar())**, onde está tablix1 você deve colocar o nome do seu DataSet e não o nome da tabela, depois você precisa informar a fonte de dados, que no seu caso é um dataTable(aqui vale salientar que eu utilizo uma collection e não um DataTable). Outra coisa muito importante é você debugar com breakPoint para verificar se o DataTable está vindo populado ou vazio e com isso já ver se os nomes das colunas do DataTable estão iguais os da Tabela do relatório(Tablix1).